# How to get UnifiedNativeAdView ad click callback

Tags: android, admob, unifiednativeadview

For some reason, I need to know when the ad clicked or the user reacts with that. but **UnifiedNativeAdView** overrides any touch click to even native banner ads.
How we can get ad user interaction callback?

Answer (score 0):

`AdLoader.Builder` has `withAdListener` with which you can set an `AdListener`. `AdListener` has the `onAdClicked` method which you can override and is called whenever the native ad is clicked.